# How do I get past the Sea Snake?

Tags: candy-box-2

How do I get past the Sea Snake in Candy Box 2? It won't die. I've even tried killing it with the enchanted Monkey Staff.

Answer (score 0):

You can't kill it. Just stay away from it. BTW Enchanted Monkey Staff sucks, get a Scythe or an Enchanted Giant Spoon.